# High CPU Usage java+struts+tomcat project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, struts2, struts-config

I have a web application that developed using j2ee and Struts 2 MVC. Sometimes my application hit near 99% CPU usage. It's only accessed by 3 or 4 users. Anybody know why this is happening? How do I know which tasks take more CPU time in my application?

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Impossible for us to know. Use a profiler. Add some logging with timing output.

Comment: r u sure it is taking 99% cpu time ,check someother apps may be taking more cpu time.goto task mngr-->process sort processes by cpu memusage if u r on windows

Comment: provide some sort of profiling details so that some one can help you here.

Comment: which version of struts2 you are using..??

Comment: what OS are you deploying on? The tools differ between the OS to diagnose high CPU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell right away what is causing this issue, could be multiple threads (or) large number of objects (which are not GCed) (or) something else. You may need to do Thread dump analysis and Heap dump analysis to figure out what is causing the high load.

Here is oracle documentation on [thread dump analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/using_threaddumps.html).

Here is tool for [Heap analysis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html)